Bookmark lines that start with a digit and are consecutive, while skipping some other lines
I have a list like following:
Peie
71,176,953
T-re
71,173,557
5-Mts
41,653,495
45678
Sia
36,136,829
36,100,829
4-Diepi
120,829
uteCra
36,100
Oct2018

Now I want to bookmark lines that start with a digit and are consecutive, while skipping 4-Diepi and 5-Mts and month lines.
I tried following regex but I failed!
^(?:4-Diepi|5-Mts|.*\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b.*)$(*SKIP)(*F)|^\d+.*\R(\d+.*)$

The line 5-Mts was not ignored
I only want to bookmark the following lines:
41,653,495
45678
36,136,829
36,100,829

where is my regex problem?

@Yunnosch read post again! - I told (The line 5-Mts was not ignored)

So there is no desired output you could show, because the result is a list which contains all input lines minus two, of which one you got unwanted. Fair enough.


What do you mean by "bookmark"? Do you mean "match"? 2. What do you mean by "consecutive? Do you mean lines that begin with a digit and are preceded or followed by a line beginning with a digit? 3. What do you mean by "...while skipping 4-Diepi and 5-Mts and month lines."? Do you mean lines containing those literals should be skipped? What about "71,173,5-Mts"? 4. What about "23,45" and "23.45" and "2A"?


I have an additional question: 5. Do you wish to match individual lines that satisfy requirements or blocks of two or more lines that satisfy requirement. "I only want to bookmark the following lines:" suggests you want to match individual lines because the four lines identified are present in two blocks.

I have downvoted your question because you have not answered the several questions I posted yesterday. I will remove that downvote if you do a proper edit of your question.

Because the (*SKIP)(*F)| pattern does not effectly check the second line of numbers. A way to fix this is to put an optional (?:^\d+.*\R)? in the beginning of the exclude pattern to filter out if the excluded pattern was on the second line:
(?:^\d+.*\R)?(?:4-Diepi|5-Mts|.*\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b.*)$(*SKIP)(*F)|^\d+.*\R(\d+.*)$

See the test cases

If the string were "1\n2\n3\n" or "1\n2\n3" "3" is not matched.

@CarySwoveland In OP's original regex it also doesn't match. I guess it is the intended behavior that it only match two consecutive lines.

Actually, if there are are an odd number of consecutive lines of numbers it won't match the last line.

Proposition A) using positive search, if it's possible
Perhaps I missed something, but wouldn't it be shorter to just try and
match what you want, "consecutive lines with numbers and commas",
instead of skipping what you don't want?
I personally would use /(?:^[\d,]+(?:\R|$)){2,}/gm to match
two lines or more with the desired digits and commas, separated
by a new line (Windows, Unix or old Mac).


const input = `Peie
71,176,953
T-re
71,173,557
5-Mts
41,653,495
45678
Sia
36,136,829
36,100,829
895,45,7
4-Diepi
120,829
uteCra
36,100
Oct2018`;

const regex = /(?:^[\d,]+(?:\r\n|\n|\r|$)){2,}/gm;

while ((match = regex.exec(input)) !== null) {
  console.log(match[0]);
}



I see here, with PCRE that it
runs in about 10 times less steps than the "skipping" version.
Proposition B) without SKIP, but with a negative lookahead
With PCRE, enabling the x flag, you can write the pattern on
several lines and also add comments:
/
# The pattern should match twice or more.
(?:
  # Begin of line.
  ^
  # But not one of these lines:
  (?!(?:4-Diepi|5-Mts|.*\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b.*)$)
  # Digits and then any chars not beeing line ending, followed by a new line or end of line.
  \d+[^\r\n]*(\R|$)
){2,}
/gmx

In action here: https://regex101.com/r/IfmDvc/7
Without the comments, for Notepad++:
(?:^(?!(?:4-Diepi|5-Mts|.*\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b.*)$)\d+[^\r\n]*(\R|$)){2,}


If the string were "1\n2\n3\n" or "1\n2\n3" "3" is not matched. Demo

@CarySwoveland Oh yes! Thanks! Very good point as I didn't read correctly the question: "consecutive" is twice or more. I would naturally replace {2} by {2,} but it's not as easy as that. I'll have to figure how to make it work with the condition to match any line starting with digits but not from the list of elements to exclude.

@CarySwoveland Thanks for your input! I made the correction :-)

As I understand, lines containing representations of positive integers, with or without commas used as thousands separators, are to be matched, provided each such line is preceded or followed by a line having the same properties.
Moreover, I read, "...while skipping 4-Diepi and 5-Mts and month lines." as a consequence of the requirement for the particular example, as opposed to part of the specification of the problem.
If my understanding is correct I believe that to match the desired lines the regex engine must support variable-length positive lookbehinds (but I would be pleased to be proven wrong). However, Notebook++ uses the PCRE regex engine, which does not have that feature.
One can, however, use the regular expression
^(?:(?<line>(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+))\R)+(?P>line)$

to match groups of such lines, after which each group can be separated into individual lines.
The m flag must be set, causing the anchors ^ and $ to respectively match the beginning and end of a line, rather than the beginning and end of the string.

For the example two blocks of lines are matched by the above expression:
41,653,495
45678

and
36,136,829
36,100,829

Demo

This expression can be broken down as follows.
^               # match beginning of a line
(?:             # begin non-capture group
  (?<line>      # begin capture group named 'line' 
    (?:         # begin non-capture group
      \d+       # match one or more digits
      |         # or
      \d{1,3}   # match one to three digits
      (?:       # begin a non-capture group
        ,\d{3}  # match a comma followed by three digits
      )+        # end non-capture group and execute one or more times
    )           # end non-capture group
  )             # end capture group 'line'
  \R            # match line terminators
)+              # end non-capture group and execute one or more times 
(?P>line)       # match the expression that defined capture group 'line'
$               # end of line

(?P>line) denotes a subroutine. The use of subroutines shortens the regular expression and makes it easier to read, but more importantly, it reduces the liklihood of the expression being written incorrectly.

Observe that if the string were
A
123
45,67
234,567

no strings would be matched because "45,67" is not a valid representation of a number.

As I understood, he wants to match any line starting with digits, so not only digits and commas (which I proposed as simplification in my A response, thinking it would be more logical). But I think it should also match 89-aka or 804,84-xxx. This was why he was using the exclusion list with the skips, which I tried to convert to a negative lookahead. Demo

Just to notice that if the file doesn't contain a terminating new line character, the pattern will not match the last consecutive lines. \R can be replaced by (?:\R|$) to solve the problem.

@Patrick, That you for the observation concerning the presence of a line terminator at the end of the string. I've corrected that. I do not know which lines the OP wishes to match. You will see that the OP has not responded to a comment I posted on on the question yesterday that asked for clarification. I therefore spelled out in my answer my understanding of the question, which is to be viewed as an assumption on which my answer rests.
